# Wrap links to in-domain UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am migrating a static web page written with ASP.net Web Forms to a more dynamic ajax page.

I'm curious if there is a way to quickly wrap any links in my domain that don't cause postbacks to simply load inside of an UpdatePanel instead of reloading the page (maybe capturing in-domain clicks and causing a postback on the wrapping UpdatePanel?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just use jQuery and get rid of the UpdatePanel.